# Socket Python Exchange

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, chat

I am trying to build a TCP Chat Program that is multithreaded. So far I think most of the functions are setup fine. When starting the server and connecting with a client only responses sent from the server are broadcasted to all clients connected. I think I figured out why that is and it comes from the CONNECTION_LIST array I have. The server appends all clients to this list and I thought I had the same thing going for the clients but the client instance never sees this list so when sending messages they messages aren't sent anywhere. I basically need a way to copy the CONNECTION_list from the server instance over to the connected clients. I been trying figure out how to possibly do this all day and its driving me crazy.

```
import socket
import platform
import threading
import sys
import time
import os

'''Define Globals'''
HOST = ""
PORT = 25000
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
CONNECTION_LIST = []
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

'''Connect Client to the Server'''
def client_connect():

    server_ip = input("[+] Server's IP to connect to: ")
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        client.connect((server_ip, PORT))
        print("[+] Connected to Server at address: %s" %client.getpeername()[0])
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print("[*] No Server Listening at Specified Address")
        sys.exit()

    communicate(client)


'''Threaded loop to continue listening for new connections'''
def server_loop():

    server.bind(ADDR)
    server.listen(10)

    print("[*] Server started on %s" %platform.node())

    while True:
        client_socket, client_addr = server.accept()
        CONNECTION_LIST.append(client_socket)
        print("\r[+] New Connection from: %s" %client_addr[0])


'''Broadcast data to all clients except sender'''
def broadcast_data(sock, message):

    for socket in CONNECTION_LIST:
        if socket != server and socket != sock:
            try:
                socket.send(str.encode("[%s] => %s" %(os.getlogin(),message)))
            except:
                socket.close()
                CONNECTION_LIST.remove(socket)


'''Server Host Connect Back'''
def self_connect():

    sc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sc.connect(("localhost", 25000))
    CONNECTION_LIST.append(sc)
    communicate(sc)


def communicate(client):

    dump_thread = threading.Thread(target=dump, args=(client,))
    dump_thread.start()

    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            data = input("> ")
            broadcast_data(client, data)
        except:
            print("[*] Error - Program Terminating")
            client.close()
            sys.exit()

def dump(client):
    while True:
        print(client.recv(1024).decode("utf-8"))


def main():

   server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server_loop)

   while True:

       try:
            print("Select Operating Mode")
            print("---------------------")
            print("1. Server Mode")
            print("2. Client Mode")
            mode = int(input("Enter mode of operation: "))
            print("\n\n")
            if mode in [1,2]:
                break
            else:
                raise ValueError
       except ValueError:
           print("Enter either (1) for Server or (2) for Client")


   if mode == 1:
        server_thread.start()
        time.sleep(1)
        self_connect()
   elif mode == 2:
       client_connect()


main()
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Each client should only communicate with the server, not with peers.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhh see I thought that too. I thought since its the server shouldn't only clients send data to it and then the server prints out what it is receiving from them.